# ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, error-handling

I've come across the abnormal situation, and can't understand what happens.

I am connecting databases using PL/SQL Developer 8.0.4.1514(I've also tried v7,but same) . Sometimes(When I am trying to log on, or when I open another session, or when I am trying to run query in previously opened session) this error message appears

[image]

Sometimes after 3 tries error resolves(using the same password on each try), sometimes it needs one try to resolve...

What may be the reason?

Thank you ...

Comment: I suspect you're typing the password incorrectly ;) As an aside, what are you doing that requires you to connect as `SYS` ?

Comment: @Phil thank you for your response. I will explain by example. I copied the password, pasted and tried to logon-> appeared error. Tried the next time by the same way -> again error, tried again by the same way(I mean pasted password) and logged on successfully. (Strange)

Comment: This seems like an application issue.  Have you contacted support for PL/SQL Developer?  You could also download version 9 to see if the problem still exists there.

Comment: @LeighRiffel I also think that this is PL/SQL Developer issue.. Now I created user with password expire and after connecting , there appeared as usual password changer window.. after trying to set new password(pressing OK) the same error happened.

Comment: It's a version incompatibility issue. Try with a more recent version for Oracle 11g R2.

Comment: is it a RAC database?

Answer (score 1):

PL/SQL Developer will remember your most recent windows. If you close the application without closing your windows, it will attempt to authenticate to restart your old sessions. This can become a nuisance if you work in several environments. Try making it habit to close everything before closing the application. You may also try upgrading the application as user21081 suggested.